# How could I handle event of a new state committed into the vault in a Corda node?

Tags: corda

I need to know when the new state got committed into the node's vault for getting the timestamp at that moment. So, I think if I can handle the committed state then trigger my timestamp record class would be nice.

By the way, please let me know if you have any suggestions about capturing timestamp on state evolving over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the `CordaRPCOps.vaultTrackBy` method. This method returns an observable of updates to the vault. You can subscribe to this observable to be notified whenever a new state is recorded in the vault.

## RPC example

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    require(args.size == 1) { "Usage: ExampleClientRPC <node address>" }
    val nodeAddress = NetworkHostAndPort.parse(args[0])
    val client = CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress)

    val rpcOps = client.start("user1", "test").proxy

    val updates = rpcOps.vaultTrackBy<ContractState>().updates

    // Log the 'placed' IOU states and listen for new ones.
    updates.toBlocking().subscribe { update ->
        update.produced.forEach { stateAndRef ->
            val timeStamp = Instant.now()
            // TODO("Use the timestamp as you wish.")
        }
    }
}
```

## Flow test example

```
class FlowTests {
    lateinit var network: MockNetwork
    lateinit var a: StartedMockNode
    lateinit var b: StartedMockNode

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        network = MockNetwork(
                listOf("com.example.contract"),
                // We need each node to operate on a separate thread so that we can
                // subscribe to the vault updates on a separate thread later.
                threadPerNode = true)
        a = network.createPartyNode()
        b = network.createPartyNode()
        listOf(a, b).forEach { it.registerInitiatedFlow(ExampleFlow.Acceptor::class.java) }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        network.stopNodes()
    }

    @Test
    fun `flowTest`() {
        // Trying to access the node database in a separate thread would result in a
        // `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Was expecting to find CordaPersistence set on current thread` exception
        val updates = a.services.vaultService.trackBy<ContractState>().updates

        Thread {
            updates.toBlocking().subscribe { update ->
                update.produced.forEach { stateAndRef ->
                    val timeStamp = Instant.now()
                    // TODO("Use the timestamp as you wish.")
                }
            }
        }.start()

        repeat(3) {
            val flow = ExampleFlow.Initiator(1, b.info.singleIdentity())
            a.startFlow(flow).getOrThrow()
        }

        // We give the other thread time to observe the updates.
        Thread.sleep(10000)
    }
}
```